# Actionscript 3: Align MC to MC Inside MC Cords

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay so I am trying to get a stage movie clip instance to align (x,y) to the x, y cords of a movie clip instance that is inside of another movie clip instance (a little confusing).

```
stageMC.x = targetMC.subTargetMC.x;
stageMC.y = targetMC.subTargetMC.y;
```

So on an event (mouse click for example), we want the x, y cords of 'stageMC' instance to align with the x, y cords of 'subTargetMC' which itself sits inside of movie clip called 'targetMC'.

The movie clip 'subTargetMC' which sits inside of the primary 'targetMC' is an instance copy of a library MC and has its instance name as indicated.

I did not find a solution in the forum nor anywhere else online. I most likely will end up resolving this myself (as I usually do) but wanted to use StackOverflow as a help resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use localToGlobal() to convert the coordinates.

```
var globalCoordinates:Point = targetMC.subTargetMC.localToGlobal(new Point());
stageMC.x = globalCoordinates.x;
stageMC.y = globalCoordinates.y;
```

Comment: Had gotten this error: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@2de68fd1 to flash.geom.Point

Comment: I don't recommend passing any parameters into `new Point()` (unless you pass in `0, 0`). If you move subTargetMC to any coordinates other than 0 it won't work as you expect.